# como enviar un file con axios sin formData?

Tags: reactjs, axios

la unica forma de enviar archivos o imagenes atraves de axios en react es con un formData??

lo pregunto porque no encontre la manera y tube que guardar cada uno de mis estados del formulario en un formData para que se puedieran enviar con un input file.

Comment: De poder, podrías, con imágenes sería más fácil que con archivos, sin embargo, sería reinventar la rueda y complicarte demasiado la vida en cosas que ya están resueltas. La pregunta para ti es, ¿Por qué no quieres usar _FormData_?

Comment: gracias por responder... y mi respuesta es que me parece mucho tramite en react tener que guardar el file en un setState para luego crear una instancia de formData para guardarlo alli para poder mandarlo por axios.

Comment: Es lo que normalmente se hace, ahora, sería mucho más difícil, tener que decodificar tu archivo para enviarlo en un string lo cual es un proceso que te tomará tiempo, y luego en tu servidor volver a codificarlo, e intentar tratarlo como archivo, sin contar todo el tema de validaciones del tipo de contenido y el tamaño de los archivos que te envían. Al final resulta en un trabajo muchísimo más largo

Comment: tienes razon bueno gracias por responder me serivio tu ayuda.